# 13.04 Dash Icon and Ubuntu Gnome-Classic Issues

Tags: unity, 12.10, icons, gnome-classic

The dash icon for Ubuntu 13.04 was "released", and a how-to on [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/how-to-install-the-13-04-unity-launcher-design-updates) Was written. Now, I followed all of the instructions, and the assets installed fine. Oh they installed alright, and now I can't get rid of them! I went through the multiple posts, but since this seems to be a new problem, none of the answers were working, and nothing new was appearing! So what I did, was I went into Gnome-Classic, just for old times sake, and I wanted to hide from the new 13.04 icons I didn't really take to. And of course what should appear covering my top, and bottom panels, but the Unity dock, with it's 13.04 Dash icon and everything. Wait, how did unity make it's way into my gnome-classic environment? I'm not really sure, but after about an hour of fooling around with Unity-Tweak and the compiz configuration, I needed something new. Would it be a bad idea to reinstall? At this point, nothing much would be lost, but I would like to stray from that idea.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-common` like the post says?

Comment: Oops, yes I did, forgot to specify that.

Comment: well since your ready to reinstall, you could try `sudo apt-get purge unity && sudo apt-get install unity` but it might break everything...

Comment: Something I might want to do from another desktop environment?

Comment: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity : Depends: libunity-core-6.0-5 (= 6.10.0-0ubuntu2) but 6.12.0-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
         Depends: unity-common (= 6.10.0-0ubuntu2) but 6.12.0-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you probably solved this by now...
If you haven't

remove the contents of

```
/usr/share/unity/6
```

and run

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-common
```